Debezium captures table but does not stream change after it starts having data
I have a debezium connector that captures a table A with 0 items, but once that table starts having some items, the connector does not create topic, stream changes etc.
I am having snapshot.mode=initial
some logs:
Adding table public.tableA to the list of capture schema tables (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:277)
Finished exporting 0 records for table 'public.tableA' (6 of 17 tables); total duration '00:00:00.003

I also noticed that (for the same connector) tables that had items initially, streaming works fine.
I thought of trying snapshot.mode=always but from what I understand this isn't a snapshot problem.
